# Align trapezium shapes in tikz generated pyramid chart properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a pyramid chart like this one below with tikz:
[image: pyramid chart as desired]

Therefore, I've conducted some research and found this thread: [3D pyramid diagram by tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657111/3d-pyramid-diagram-by-tikz)

Taking the example from the thread above, I adapted it to fit my needs which resulted in this code:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        3d trapezium angle/.code={
            \def\threedtrapeziumangle{#1}
        },
        3d trapezium angle=60,
        3d trapezium/.style={
            shape=trapezium,
            trapezium angle=\threedtrapeziumangle,
            trapezium stretches body=true,
            line width=0pt,
            inner xsep=0pt,
            fill=#1!75!black,
            text=white,
            font=\bfseries,
            text height=.8em,
            text depth=.2em,
            append after command={
                \pgfextra{ 
                    \fill[#1!50!black] (\tikzlastnode.bottom left corner) --     
                    (\tikzlastnode.bottom right corner) -- 
                    ([shift={(-.1,-.33)}]\tikzlastnode.bottom right corner) -- 
                    ([shift={(.1,-.33)}]\tikzlastnode.bottom left corner) --
                    cycle;
                }
            }
        },
        triangle cap/.append style={
            append after command={
                \pgfextra{ 
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.top left corner);
                    \pgfgetlastxy{\temptopleftx}{\temptoplefty}
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.top right corner);
                    \pgfgetlastxy{\temptoprightx}{\temptoprighty}
                    \fill[#1!75!black] (\tikzlastnode.top left corner) --     
                    (\tikzlastnode.top right corner) -- 
                    ([shift={(0,{tan(\threedtrapeziumangle)*0.5*(\temptoprightx-\temptopleftx)*1pt})}]\tikzlastnode.top side) --
                    cycle;
                }
            }
        },
        flag/.style={
            rectangle,
            anchor=west,
            yshift=-1ex,
            xshift=3ex,
            left color=#1!50!black,
            right color=transparent!0,
            opacity=.8,
            text opacity=1,
            align=left,
            text width=17.5em,
            text height=.8em,
            text depth=.2em,
            execute at begin node=\hspace{1cm},
        },
        ]
        
        \node[flag=red] at (0,0) (f-1) {5. Unternehmensebene};
    \node[3d trapezium=red, triangle cap=red, minimum width={3cm*sin(65)}] at (0,0) (a-1) {ERP};
    
    \node[flag=orange] at ({1*cos(65)},{-1*sin(65)}) (f-2) {4. Betriebsleitebene};
    \node[3d trapezium=orange, minimum width={2cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-1*sin(65)}) (a-2) {\small MES, OPC UA};
    
    \node[flag=yellow] at ({2*cos(65)},{-2*sin(65)}) (f-3) {3. Prozessleitebene};
    \node[3d trapezium=yellow, minimum width={3cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-2*sin(65)}) (a-3) {\small SCADA, PROFIBUS};
    
    \node[flag=green] at ({3*cos(65)},{-3*sin(65)}) (f-4) {2. Steuerungsebene};
    \node[3d trapezium=green, minimum width={5cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-3*sin(65)}) (a-4) {PLC/SPS, PROFINET};
    
    \node[flag=cyan] at ({4*cos(65)},{-4*sin(65)}) (f-5) {1. Feld-/Prozessebene};
    \node[3d trapezium=cyan, minimum width={7cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-4*sin(65)}) (a-5) {Sensoren/Aktoren};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Compiled, it should look like the image below. The colours in the example above are different from the image to make it easier for you to compile straight away.

[image: customized pyramid chart]

As you can see the neon green line indicates the angle at which each trapezium shape should be aligned to as in the original example:

[image: original pyramid chart used as example]

I tried to adjust the minimum width of each trapezium shape, but the results were not satisfying.
Do you have other ideas I could try to align them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some analysis, not yet an answer, as some things seem ... .... // Turned out: this answer DOES provide a solution at the end.

#### 1) Code can't compile

- a few statements are missing at the beginning (and at the end)
- your colors (secondary1 ..) are undefined

#### 2) Preliminary code, with focus on the trapezii

Here seems to be a major problem. One is: shape trapezium doesn't always behave as on expects. However, there's more noise to your code. Let's pick one line:

```
\node[3d trapezium...] at (0,0) (a-1) {ERP};
```

`(a-1)` doesn't seem to hurt, but it also doesn't contribute. Is it a kind of memo? // Well, this is a very obscure part. The effect is a backwards counting ... but why don't you just write it as text, like `\node ... {5. Unternehmensebene};`?

Next, you work a lot with angle `65` degrees: what determines this peculiar value? Unless I overread something, even the 3d trapezium doesn't define it.

Also, the angle is not relevant for placing the trapezii, as you can see from the help lines grid: they are just placed centered at (0,0), (0,-1) ... (0,-4).

However, the option like `minimum width={7cm*sin(65)}` has a relevant impact, and what's probably "wrong" is the cm-widths for the other ones.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        3d trapezium angle/.code={
            \def\threedtrapeziumangle{#1}
        },
        3d trapezium angle=60,
        3d trapezium/.style={
            shape=trapezium,
            trapezium angle=\threedtrapeziumangle,
            trapezium stretches body=true,
            line width=0pt,
            inner xsep=0pt,
            fill=#1!75!black,
            text=white,
            font=\bfseries,
            text height=.8em,
            text depth=.2em,
            append after command={
                \pgfextra{ 
                    \fill[#1!50!black] (\tikzlastnode.bottom left corner) --     
                    (\tikzlastnode.bottom right corner) -- 
                    ([shift={(-.1,-.33)}]\tikzlastnode.bottom right corner) -- 
                    ([shift={(.1,-.33)}]\tikzlastnode.bottom left corner) --
                    cycle;
                }
            }
        },
        triangle cap/.append style={
            append after command={
                \pgfextra{ 
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.top left corner);
                    \pgfgetlastxy{\temptopleftx}{\temptoplefty}
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.top right corner);
                    \pgfgetlastxy{\temptoprightx}{\temptoprighty}
                    \fill[#1!75!black] (\tikzlastnode.top left corner) --     
                    (\tikzlastnode.top right corner) -- 
                    ([shift={(0,{tan(\threedtrapeziumangle)*0.5*(\temptoprightx-\temptopleftx)*1pt})}]\tikzlastnode.top side) --
                    cycle;
                }
            }
        },
        flag/.style={
            rectangle,
            anchor=west,
            yshift=-1ex,
            xshift=3ex,
            left color=#1!50!black,
            right color=transparent!0,
            opacity=.8,
            text opacity=1,
            align=left,
            text width=17.5em,
            text height=.8em,
            text depth=.2em,
            execute at begin node=\hspace{1cm},
        },
        ]
        
        % !!! undefined colors !!!!
        \colorlet{secondary1}{green}
        \colorlet{secondary2}{green!50}
        \colorlet{secondary3}{blue}
        \colorlet{secondary4}{blue!50}
        \colorlet{secondary5}{blue}
        \colorlet{secondary6}{blue!50}
        
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (5,-5);        
        
 %       \node[flag=secondary1] at (0,0) (f-1) {5. Unternehmensebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary1, triangle cap=secondary1, minimum width={3cm*sin(65)}] at (0,0) (a-1) {ERP};
        
 %       \node[flag=secondary2] at ({1*cos(65)},{-1*sin(65)}) (f-2) {4. Betriebsleitebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary2, minimum width={2cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-1*sin(65)}) (a-2) {\small MES, OPC UA};
%        
%        \node[flag=secondary3] at ({2*cos(65)},{-2*sin(65)}) (f-3) {3. Prozessleitebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary3, minimum width={3cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-2*sin(65)}) (a-3) {\small SCADA, PROFIBUS};
%        
%        \node[flag=secondary4] at ({3*cos(65)},{-3*sin(65)}) (f-4) {2. Steuerungsebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary4, minimum width={5cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-3*sin(65)}) (a-4) {PLC/SPS, PROFINET};
%        
%        \node[flag=secondary5] at ({4*cos(65)},{-4*sin(65)}) (f-5) {1. Feld-/Prozessebene};
       \node[3d trapezium=secondary5, minimum width={7cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-4*sin(65)}) (a-5) {Sensoren/Aktoren};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### 3) Trying intuition

So, why not using `7cm`, `6cm` ... `3cm` in the options? Seems to work :)

[image: result]

```
        \node[flag=secondary1] at (0,0) (f-1) {5. Unternehmensebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary1, triangle cap=secondary1, minimum width={3cm*sin(65)}] at (0,0) (a-1) {ERP};
        
        \node[flag=secondary2] at ({1*cos(65)},{-1*sin(65)}) (f-2) {4. Betriebsleitebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary2, minimum width={4cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-1*sin(65)}) (a-2) {\small MES, OPC UA};
        
        \node[flag=secondary3] at ({2*cos(65)},{-2*sin(65)}) (f-3) {3. Prozessleitebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary3, minimum width={5cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-2*sin(65)}) (a-3) {\small SCADA, PROFIBUS};
        
        \node[flag=secondary4] at ({3*cos(65)},{-3*sin(65)}) (f-4) {2. Steuerungsebene};
        \node[3d trapezium=secondary4, minimum width={6cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-3*sin(65)}) (a-4) {PLC/SPS, PROFINET};
       
        \node[flag=secondary5] at ({4*cos(65)},{-4*sin(65)}) (f-5) {1. Feld-/Prozessebene};
       \node[3d trapezium=secondary5, minimum width={7cm*sin(65)}] at (0,{-4*sin(65)}) (a-5) {Sensoren/Aktoren};
```

#### 4) Final suggestions

- clean up the nodes, i.e. remove `(a-1)` etc.
- do some refactoring, i.e. unify duplicate or repeatative parts, e.g. by using `\pic` or `\for`
- to help us helping you: post only code, which compiles after copying, to keep us from guessworking, i.e. keep us on focus onto your problem, not your syntax

Comment: 1) yes, that's my bad, I altered the colour codes so it can be compiled right away.
2) the angle comes from the example in the linked thread. 
3) Testing has shown that `3cm` `4cm` `5cm` `6.5cm` `7.5cm` work best for me
4) I'm not familiar with the commands in your second bullet point, so I'll take that as a future to-do with me